# Is there a hotkey to instantly change the monitor to a specific brightness?

Tags: keyboard, display

There are too many scales on brightness. Apple even allows users to press Shift+Option+F1/F2 to fine tune at a smaller step. However, I want to take a giant step. I want to press F1 to jump to 25% brightness, press F1 again to 0%. I don't want to use a slider. Using a hotkey in the keyboard is much quicker.

Is there such an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in Shortcuts app [image] can do this, and you don't need to code. Create a new shortcut, search for 'brightness', select it and change the value as needed.

[image]

Then click the Details [image] button on the right. Click the 'Add Keyboard Shortcut' button, and press the keys you want to use to activate this shortcut:

[image]

Close the window, and the keyboard shortcut will work in all applications but Shortcuts.

Comment: That looks fantastic! However, it seems only Monterey has this built-in Shortcuts app. I use Big Sur on M1 macbook air. I only have 8GB RAM, and don't have the storage room for upgrading(19GB left). Plus, I am worried about compability with my softwares. Is there anothe way, for example using built-in Automator? I'm willing to learn a little code if it's not too complicated for an outsider.

Comment: That's a pity. I'm not familiar with Automator, sorry ...

Comment: Your answer will be of great help to others!

Answer (score 1):

I found an app called "Keyboard Maestro", which can achieve this function in my BigSur.

As shown in the picture below, I press F1 once to repeat "decrease screen brightness" 8 times.

[image]